# How does a Thorne Zytkow star die?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, neutron-stars, supernova

A Thorne-Zytkow star is one where a red giant or supergiant contains a neutron star at its core, formed from the collision of the giant with the neutron star. It is believed that one has been found in the Small Megellanic Cloud.

The wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorne%E2%80%93%C5%BBytkow_object) states that the TZO may either form form a black hole or end up with a neutron star with a accretion disc...

My question, is wouldn't the intense gravity of the NS at its core cause the star to collapse in on itself, triggering a supernova from the shock wave?

Comment: That Wikipedia link says: *"When the two finally collide, the neutron star and red giant core will merge. If their combined mass exceeds the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff limit then the two will collapse into a black hole, resulting in a supernova that disperses the outer layers of the star"*. It also mentions the extreme temperature of the NS, which tends to slow down red giant matter that's attracted to the NS.